# Application.css not updating in production with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

My application.css is not changing when I push to heroku.

```
rake assets:precompile # does some things
git add-commit -m "..."
git push heroku master
```

**Application.css:**

```
*
*= require foundation_and_overrides
* required other files
*/

body {
 background: red
}
```

**Production env:**

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Nothing works, my background is white even if it's set to red. How does the pipeline works with heroku and rails 5, please?

Comment: Looks like Heroku hasn't updated their docs for Rails 5 yet, but this might be helpful: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: Hi @NickM. bkunzi01's answer did the trick. Thanks for that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run bundle exec `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` or it will use your development environment config settings for precompiliation.  Also, to force that the fingerprint digest changes I want you to add a comment at the very top of your application.css file so it looks like this:

```
/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/* Adding a comment to force a new digest and expire cached assets in browsers */
```

Also, make sure to include the heroku gem for serving assets in your gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Also, as a sidenote, you're asking for major performance decreases when setting `config.assets.compile = true`

You should make sure to find any missing assets and fix the assets paths before deploying to production and keeping the assets.compile=false

Comment: My gemfile is ok but `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` worked. Thanks, buddy.

Comment: No problem!  Good luck